# How to do backup and restore to SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I can't do backup and restore to SQL Server with C# code.

How can my client do backup and restore to database on his PC?

Comment: I don't see any programming question here.. Smells like off-topic.

Comment: Please avoid "thank you notes", "I'm novice" and other text not related to your problem. Also saying "I can't find anything on internet" does not show real effort to find solution...

Answer (score 1):

Backup and Restore SQL Server databases programmatically with SMO, Check [**THIS**](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1849/backup-and-restore-sql-server-databases-programmatically-with-smo/)

You can do

1. Full Backups
2. Differential Backups
3. Transaction Log Backups
4. Backup with Compression
5. Full or Differential Restores
6. Transaction Log Restore
7. Database Restore to a new location

*But the disadvantage with this method is that it needs your SQL Management Studio to be installed on your client system.*

Answer (score 1):

Go to Sql Server Management Studio
Select your server , give authentication details and connect with your server Database.

Right click the Database, Generate the Script of Database

Save it.

Log out from Studio, and Re-Login on to your client machine authentication details and run that script.

Database will generate on your client machine too.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make or restore a database backup on a client computer, unless it's in the same local network as the server so that the server can access the disk on the client computer.

Generally you would make and restore backups on the server, and then upload/download to the client computer.

Comment: Can I Do This With  C# ??

Comment: Yes, you can. There are plenty of example available on how to do backups, and how to do upload/download, you only need to put the two together.

Comment: All I need no loss of data in case of system failure in the client machine
How can I keep the data from being lost on the client machine